# Python str.contains

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I use this code to see if details contain Mercedes and details contains `123`.
How do I do to get details that  contain Mercedes and doesn't contains `123`.

```py
color1 = "Mercedes 123"
color2 = "Green not sold"

#----- Applying the condition
df['check'] = df['check'].mask(df['Details'].str.contains('Mercedes') & df['Details'].str.contains('123'), color1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `and` to combine the conditions and `not` to negate the second condition:

```py
color1 = "Mercedes 123"
color2 = "Green not sold"

#----- Applying the condition
df['check'] = df['check'].mask(df['Details'].str.contains('Mercedes') and not df['Details'].str.contains('123'), color1)
```